# How do I overwrite SRT subtitles in an M4V file without transcoding audio and video and remove the older subtitles

Tags: ffmpeg, subtitles

I recently encoded an M4V with the incorrect subtitles. The subtitles were from another video and don’t make sense in the context of the video they were muxed into.

How can I replace the existing/incorrect SRT subtitles with the correct subtitles using FFmpeg?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After looking at a few different solutions to *add* items to an existing M4V — but not remove existing subtitles — I managed to cobble the following command together and it works fine for me. It copies over only the video, sets the subtitle metadata to “eng” (aka: English) and sets the subtitles to be the default subtitles:

```
ffmpeg -i input.m4v -sub_charenc ISO-8859-1 -sn -i input.srt -c:s mov_text -c:v copy -c:a copy -map 0:v -map 0:a -map 1 -disposition:s:0 default -metadata:s:s:0 language=eng output.m4v
```

Note the the subtitles I am dealing with are not UTF-8; they are encoded as ISO-8859-1 thus the `-sub_charenc` which can be removed or adjusted based on your own subtitle needs.